# How to check if a python package is installed using poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'm using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) to manage my Python project, and I would like to check if a package is installed. This means the package is actually fetched from the remote repository and is located in the `.venv/` folder. I went through the official documentation but didn't find any command that can do that.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Update: I ended up with a solution by running the following command and parsing its output.

Thanks all for the help here!

`poetry install --dry-run --sync --no-ansi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have activated the virtual environment in the `.venv` folder (using, for example `source .venv/bin/activate`), you can use `pip list` to list all of the installed packages in that virtual environment. There is a `poetry show` command to list all available packages as well that you might want to look into: https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#show

Update:

You can parse the output of the `poetry install --dry-run` command to see what packages are installed, without actually installing any packages. Look for the lines with both "Installing" and "Skipped" and "reason: Already installed", to see what packages are already installed.

Comment: Thanks! `poetry show` almost gives me the results that I want, but it displays the names of uninstalled packages in red in the console. How can I programmatically parse its output and perform the check?

Comment: `pip list` may not be helpful because I also need to check whether a package is installed globally via `poetry self add/install`.

Comment: I see that packages are output in red when they are not installed in the virtual environment, but listed as dependencies in `pyproject.toml`. It seems like a bit of a hack, but you might try running `poetry install --dry-run`. You can then parse the "Installing" lines that are not "Skipped". This won't actually install any packages, but it will give you the output as if it did.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to check whether a particular package is installed in your poverty environment.
You can use `poetry show <packagename>` command which will show package information.

```
niraj@HOST-ANALYTICS:~/Work/Code/apitutorialsnew$ poetry show pandas
 name         : pandas                                                                  
 version      : 1.5.3                                                                   
 description  : Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics 

dependencies
 - numpy >=1.20.3
 - numpy >=1.21.0
 - python-dateutil >=2.8.1
 - pytz >=2020.1

required by
 - seaborn >=0.25
 - statsmodels >=0.25
```

Answer (score -1):

import pkgutil

package_name = "package_name"  # Replace with the name of the package you want to check

## Check if the package is installed

```
if pkgutil.find_loader(package_name):
    print(f"{package_name} is installed.")
else:
    print(f"{package_name} is not installed.")
```